# Best answer for why destructors are called from derived to base?

Tags: destructor

I recently attended a interview where the person asked me what is order of construction and destruction. I explained that construction happened from base to child and destruction from child to base.

The interviewer was keen in knowing is there any special reason for destruction happening from derived to base. I explained him, but he was not convinced.

His point was what if base class destruction give exception, how would derived class know as derived class object would be already destructed.

He was also telling that derived class contains base class members so why can't we call base class destruction first?

I explained that after derived class destruction is done, we cannot say object is fully destructed.

Am i right here? what is the best answer here?

Comment: Is this about C++? Then please tag it appropriately. Not all languages use the same order of construction as C++.

Comment: NOTE: This was a C# interview, but the interviewer asked me to tell in general assuming i have destructor in class

Comment: In C# initializers run before the constructors and in the opposite "direction" starting with the initializers for the most derived class: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two.aspx

Comment: If destruction happened the other way around, base to derived, then why could we not say the object is fully destructed after the derived class destruction is done? At this point destruction would have occurred on every level...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# Object construction follows this order:

1. Initialization of data members Derived -> Base
2. Execution of Constructors Base -> Derived.

Why?

- Initialization follows Derived -> Base to avoid reinitialization of members initialized differently in the Derived from the base.
- Construction follows Base -> Derived because the Derived constructor may rely on methods of the Base class.

Other languages handle the initialization differently, but the Base-> Derived construction is typical.

Destruction is done from Derived -> Base.

Why?

- The Derived may still use rely on resources allocated by the Base during destruction.

  - If the Base were destroyed first, these resources would no longer be available for the Derived.
- Each level of the heirarchy should be responsible for freeing up any resouces allocated by that level.

  - Base could not free the Derived Class's resources it has no knowledge of them.
  - Derived should also not be resposible for resources allocated by the Base

    - In strict OOP the derived shouldn't even know the details of those resources, or in what manner they are allocated or released.

To respond to his specific points:

- Exception in the base

  - Exceptions should not be thrown in destructors (In Particular in C# this at least at one time could kill the garbage collector)
- Derived classes contain Base class members

  - The object has one instance of any data member. Not one per level of heirarchy.
    So we return to if the base frees the resources associated with a data member, it will no longer be available for the Derived class to use.

To your explanation for the reasoning of the order. If we assume the Derived->Base order is correct, that explains why you must still call the Base destructor, but not why Derived comes first.
If the concerns regarding the order were different, and the destruction were completed Base->Derived then we would be able to consider the object completely destructed after the Derived destructor completed as destruction would have occurred on all levels.

Comment: Mr.Mindor I woud like to ask about this line here: 
Initialization follows Derived -> Base to avoid reinitialization of members initialized differently in the Derived from the base.   why would they be reinitialized if the two initialize completely different members?

Comment: @EricMovsessian This would be in the case that the derived class overrides the initialization of a member that exists in the base. If the two initialize completely different members there would be no opportunity to reinitialize anything.

Comment: Mr.Mindor, thank you very much for reaching out. I am so afraid that I do not understand what you mean by overriding initialization. Can you please help?

Comment: Actually I think I see It now. So basically in cases where you would use the same name for a member that is in both base and derived classes. So does It mean when the member in the derived gets initialized and the compiler hits another member in the base with the same name, then It kind of ignores It?

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right.  I used to ask this question frequently when interviewing experienced C++ programmers.  The derived class must be constructed after the base class so that the derived class constructor can refer to base class data.  For the same reason, the derived class destructor must run before the base class destructor.  It's very logical: we construct from the inside out, and destroy from the outside in.  If the base class destructor throws an exception, it cannot be caught by the derived class destructor.  Nor can an exception in a base class constructor be handled by a derived class constructor.  In general, exceptions should not be thrown from destructors.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that object construction occurs in stages.  If you have a class B derived from A, you construct B by first constructing an A and then turning the A into a B.  Likewise, a B is destroyed by first turning it into an A, and then destroying the A.  This provides a very consistent way of thinking about object creation and destruction.